# Retrieve data 14 days prior to their "date of manufacture" irrespective of Year in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need all the rows that are 14 days next to my current date and that should not depend upon the Year. For example if today is  2nd of September, then the query should return all the rows of which u_dateofmanufacture is (2+14) 16th September, no matter which year it belongs. the focus is only on the date and the month.

I have also attached the screenshot and the column "date of Manufacture" is highlighted.

According to the screenshot only the rows 2,3 and 4 should be returned. They all have different year but the day and month is same(09-16).

[image: picl1]

I am using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @date DATE = dateadd(d,14,getdate()) 

select * from your table where month(u_dateofmanufacture)= month(@date) and day(u_dateofmanufacture) = day(@date)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a query like below

```
select * from yourtable
where month(u_dateofmanufacture)= month(dateadd(d,14,getdate())) 
and day(u_dateofmanufacture) =day(dateadd(d,14,getdate()))
```

optimally

```
declare @seekdate = dateadd(d,14,getdate())
select * from yourtable
    where month(u_dateofmanufacture)= month(@seekdate ) 
    and day(u_dateofmanufacture) =day(@seekdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with leap years and the first 14 days of the year.  If we skip these problems, you can use:

```
where month(datecol + 14) * 100 + day(datecol + 14) >= month(getdate()) * 100 + day(getdate()) and
      month(datecol) * 100 + day(datecol) < month(getdate()) * 100 + day(getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a join on a virtual table containing all the possible years

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM YourTable t
JOIN (
    SELECT
        starting = DATEADD(day, -14, DATEFROMPARTS(v.year, MONTH(GETDATE(), DAY(GETDATE())),
        ending = DATEFROMPARTS(v.year, MONTH(GETDATE(), DAY(GETDATE())) 
    FROM (VALUES
      (2023),(2022),(2022),(2021),(2020),(2019),(2018),(2017),(2016),(2015),(2014),(2013),(2012),(2011)
    ) v(year)
) v ON t.u_dateofmanufacture >= v.starting
   AND t.u_dateofmanufacture <  v.ending
```